# SOLR collections update failure

Tags: solr, lucene

I am new to apache solr. I have installed the apache solr 3.4 on my local machine and tried to index the 'sample_core' collection by dataimport Handler.

I have run the full-import by below url.

http://localhost:8983/solr/sample_core/dataimport/?command=full-import&clean=true

And keep on checking the status of dataimport handler by using the below url.

http://localhost:8983/solr/sample_core/dataimport/?command=status

I am getting the message "Indexing completed" but still dataimport handler showing busy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
   <lst name="responseHeader">
      <int name="status">0</int>
      <int name="QTime">0</int>
   </lst>
   <lst name="initArgs">
      <lst name="defaults">
         <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
      </lst>
   </lst>
   <str name="command">status</str>
   <str name="status">busy</str>
   <str name="importResponse">A command is still running...</str>
   <lst name="statusMessages">
      <str name="Time Elapsed">0:0:55.158</str>
      <str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">0</str>
      <str name="Total Rows Fetched">1349</str>
      <str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
      <str name="Full Dump Started">2017-04-19 12:07:35</str>
      <str name="">Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 1349 documents. Deleted 0 documents.</str>
   </lst>
   <str name="WARNING">This response format is experimental. It is likely to change in the future.</str>
</response>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are starting with Solr you should pick a current version (like 6.5 or 6.4 at least). Solr 3.4 is ancient.

If it says 'indexing completed' then it ended already. DIH dashboard page has sometimes been slow updating status, and I have seen return older statuses plenty of time, so don't worry about that part.